# Why isn't my homemade pepperoni orange?

Tags: curing

I bought a large pork shoulder, broke it down into manageable pieces (it's just myself and my wife), and with one piece I decided to make pepperoni. I followed what seemed to be a pretty standard recipe:

1. Grind
2. Add spices (fennel, red pepper, garlic) and tender quick
3. Dry in fridge
4. Slow-roast to 160°F

If I close my eyes, it tastes like pepperoni, but it looks nothing like it. Much more red--almost purplish red, but by no means the greasy orange slice I'd expect on a pizza. I guess it could do fine in a stromboli, but I'd like to know what I did wrong, or what I'd need to do to get what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepperoni):

> Sodium nitrite, used as a curing agent, is what gives pepperoni the pink part of its distinct orange-pink color, while paprika or other capsicum provides the orange part.

It cites a [food science blog article](http://howfoodworks.blogspot.com/2009/02/pepperoni-is-raw-meat.html) as the source.

Comment: Yes, it's added to help kill bacteria during the curing process. It's the same stuff that makes pastrami red.

Comment: Fair enough, however, as noted, I did use tender quick (you might be aware that this contains sodium nitrite). The cure did cause the meat to turn red, just not the orange color I was expecting.

Comment: @Ray: Well, before I posted that article, my first thought was "Paprika?" - which you'll note from what was written causes the orange colour.